# Update Nodejs 14->18 — webpack have the same syntaxError: /.../xxx.vue: Unexpected token, expected "," (1:8) for ALL Vue 2 components in the project

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-loader

I updated Nodejs version on my Vue 2 project from 14 to 18 (16 has the same issue). It was fine in the beginning. But, at some point in the last month when I decided to clean up Docker caches, images, containers, and volumes — and, rebuild Docker containers — then it started to produce the "SyntaxError":

```
ERROR in ./src/views/404.vue?vue&type=template&id=6b3aeb0e& (./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5]!./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/views/404.vue?vue&type=template&id=6b3aeb0e&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /opt/application/src/views/404.vue: Unexpected token, expected "," (1:8)

> 1 | [object Promise]
    |         ^
  2 | export { render, staticRenderFns }
    at instantiate (/Users/dmitrydudin/harlem/chat-home-base/ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:63:32)
    at constructor (/Users/dmitrydudin/harlem/chat-home-base/ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:358:12)
    at JSXParserMixin.raise (/Users/dmitrydudin/harlem/chat-home-base/ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3207:19)
    at JSXParserMixin.unexpected (/Users/dmitrydudin/harlem/chat-home-base/ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3237:16)
    ...
```

I have the same error for absolutely all Vue components.

Most Vue components are pretty standard, for example, `404.vue` is even empty:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({});
</script>
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "ui",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.10",
        "@lottiefiles/lottie-player": "^1.7.1",
        "@mdi/font": "^5.3.45",
        "@types/debounce": "^1.2.0",
        "@types/intl": "^1.2.0",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
        "@types/pluralize": "0.0.29",
        "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.33",
        "@web-types/vuetify": "^2.0.15-1",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "axios-retry": "^3.6.0",
        "core-js": "^3.32.0",
        "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
        "debounce": "^1.2.1",
        "emoji-mart-vue-fast": "6.1.1",
        "emoji-regex": "^9.2.2",
        "firebase": "^9.23.0",
        "firebase-tools": "^11.30.0",
        "flush-promises": "^1.0.2",
        "grapheme-splitter": "^1.0.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
        "qs": "^6.11.2",
        "resize-observer": "^1.0.4",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.7.2",
        "stackdriver-errors-js": "^0.8.0",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
        "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
        "v-calendar": "^2.3.0",
        "vue": "^2.7.14",
        "vue-class-component": "^7.2.6",
        "vue-easy-lightbox": "^0.14.1",
        "vue-flagpack": "^1.0.1",
        "vue-gravatar": "^1.3.1",
        "vue-hotjar": "^1.4.0",
        "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
        "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
        "vue-sanitize": "^0.2.2",
        "vue-socket.io-extended": "^4.2.0",
        "vue2-timepicker": "^1.1.6",
        "vue-loader": "^15.10.1",
        "vuetify": "^2.3.23",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2",
        "webpack": "^5.88.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
        "@types/jest": "^27.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^18.14.6",
        "@types/qs": "^6.9.6",
        "@types/resize-observer-browser": "^0.1.7",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.11",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.11",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.8",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.8",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.8",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.8",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.8",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.8",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.3",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
        "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0",
        "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-require-context": "^0.1.1",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001328",
        "eslint": "8.42.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.14.1",
        "http-request": "^0.7.0",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "jest": "^27.1.0",
        "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
        "prettier-eslint": "^11.0.0",
        "process": "^0.11.10",
        "sass": "~1.32.12",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "ts-jest": "^27.1.5",
        "typescript": "4.4.4",
        "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "vuepress": "^1.7.1",
        "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0",
        "vuex-class": "^0.3.2",
        "vuex-module-decorators": "^0.17.0"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "@vue/cli-service": {
            "vue-loader": "^15.10.1"
        }
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead"
    ],
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

I found that it can be an issue with `vue-loader` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74718715/2044408

> vue-loader 16+ isn't compatible with vue 2.x
> ...
> So you need to use vue-loader 15.x

Thus, I tried to explicitly define:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "vue-loader": "^15.10.1",
  ...
}
```

But anyway, I always see `vue-loader v17` in `package-lock.json`:

```
"node_modules/@vue/cli-service": {
  "version": "5.0.8",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried to override it in the `package.json` file:

```
  "overrides": {
    "@vue/cli-service": {
      "vue-loader": "^15.10.1"
    }
  },
```

It seems not working.
But I didn't manage to completely change `vue-loader` version 17 -> 15.

---

I also tried to revert the code state of 2 months ago (with full cleaning Docker things) — the error is sticky now. Can something happen with the registry?

I can't manage to figure out what it is and how to fix this...

---

UPD:
I found that if I try to create a completely fresh Vue 2 (TS, Webpack) project — then I have the same issue after I add Eslint+Prettier packages:

```
"eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
"prettier": "^3.0.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after a couple of days of research and tests:

I just added the Prettier package to `devDependencies`:

```
"prettier": "2.8.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `trailingComma` has been changed in pretteir 3, so this is the effect.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#trailing-commas

> Default value changed from es5 to all in v3.0.0

Vue-loader auto-formats using prettier by default when compiling, but you can optionally turn off that behavior.

Below is an example of `webpack.mix.js`.

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          // https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#prettify
          // In development mode, we use prettier to format the compiled render function for ease of debugging by default.
          // However, if you encounter any obscure bug of prettier, such as exponential compilation time for deeply nested functions,
          // you can disable this option to circumvent it.
          prettify: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
});
```